# Multi-column interpolation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I want to use `scipy` or `pandas` to interpolate on a table like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'y':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'z':[10,20,30,40,50,60] })

df = 
   x   y   z
0  1   1  10
1  1   2  20
2  1   3  30
3  2   1  40
4  2   2  50
5  2   3  60
```

I want to be able to interpolate for a `x` value of 1.5 and a `y` value of 2.5 and obtain a 40.

The process would be:

1. Starting from the first interpolation parameter (`x`), find the values that surround the target value. In this case the target is 1.5 and the surrounding values are 1 and 2.
2. Interpolate in `y` for a target of 2.5 considering `x=1`. In this case between rows 1 and 2, obtaining a 25
3. Interpolate in `y` for a target of 2.5 considering `x=2`. In this case between rows 4 and 5, obtaining a 55
4. Interpolate the values form previous steps to the target `x` value. In this case I have 25 for `x=1` and 55 for `x=2`. The interpolated value for 1.5 is 40

The order in which interpolation is to be performed is fixed and the data will be correctly sorted.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926786/efficient-method-for-multi-level-linear-interpolation-in-python) but I'm wondering if there is a standard solution already available in those libraries.

Comment: How is that interpolation if the value is fixed/ How did you get 25 for interpolation of 1?

Comment: The idea is that you interpolate in order. So first you start with x. The target x value 1.5 is between 1 and 2. Then you go to the values of x=1 and then interpolate in y. The target y value of 2.5 is between 2 and 3 (rows 1 and 2). Here you obtain the 25. Then you repeat the process for x=2. And then interpolate between both x values.

Comment: Why go for x=1 instead of x=2?

Comment: I've tried to clarify the process in the question. The idea is that it's a multi-level interpolation. So the first parameter is X and the second in Y. What you need to do is find the x values that surround your target. The target is 1.5 so the values surrounding that are 1 and 2.

Comment: Then you need to interpolate in Y considering those two values for X. That's why you first consider x=1 and then x=2. And finally you interpolate between those two X values. It's hard to explain but the process is not so complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`:

```
    import scipy.interpolate

    f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(df.x, df.y, df.z)
    f([1.5], [2.5])
     [40.]
```

The first line creates an interpolation function `z = f(x, y)` using three arrays for `x`, `y`, and `z`. The second line uses this function to interpolate for `z` given values for `x` and `y`. The default is linear interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Define your interpolate function:

```
def interpolate(x, y, df):
    cond = df.x.between(int(x), int(x) + 1) & df.y.between(int(y), int(y) + 1)
    return df.loc[cond].z.mean()

interpolate(1.5,2.5,df)
 40.0
```